# CSS Background picture not showing after hosting transition

Tags: html, css

I need some help with figuring out why my CSS background picture suddenly is not showing up. I had been hosting with Yahoo but their server was really slow so I switched to host gator. After transferring everything to them I noticed the picture was not showing... turned out a file extension had been uploaded in caps. changed it and everything worked fine. However now the picture has disappeared and I can't get it back. I haven't changed anything between then and now. am I missing something? Please help!

```css
/* Header */

#header {
  background: #333333 url("../images/pic01.jpg") !important; no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6em 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 0% 65%;
  position: relative;
}

#header:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(16, 32, 48, 0.25);
}

#header > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.homepage #header {
  padding: 8em 0;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>AIC Consulting &amp; Design</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="homepage">



<!-- Header -->
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px">
  <h1>
    <img  alt="AIC Consulting and Design Logo" longdesc="Blue circle with AIC consulting and Design in front of a feather" "relative" src="images/Logo-transparent.gif" height="71"  >&nbsp; Creations made to your design.
  </h1>
</div>
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Logo -->

    <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="websites.html">Website Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="id.html">Instructional Design</a><ul>
          <li><a href="technology.html">Technology Integration</a></li>
          <li><a href="usability.html">Usability testing</a></li>
          <li><a href="needs.html">Needs Assessment</a></li>
          <li><a href="training.html">Training Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="video.html">Video Production</a></li>
      <li><a href="publishing.html">Academic Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="organizers.html">For Organizers</a></li>
          <li><a href="authors.html">For Authors</a></li>
        </ul>     
      </li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:aicconsulting@annsinkycreations.com; aicconsulting@comcast.net">Email AIC Consulting 
&amp; Design, LLC</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? You're referencing the file with the relative path `../images/pic01.jpg`, so `pic01.jpg` needs to be in an `images` folder that is one level up from the CSS file you are including it on (so it needs to be at the same level as your `css` folder).

Comment: Can you check your browser console for what error you are getting. In google chrome you can press F12 Key for opening browser console.

Comment: @ObsidianAge it is pointing to the right directory. this image was working properly just last week

Comment: @OmSao I am looking through the errors but I don't see anything relating to the image

Comment: @AnnAbdelzaher Can you link your site.

Comment: Can you navigate to the file in a web browser?

For example, www.yoursite.com/images/pic01.jpg

Comment: @Sand www.annsinkycreations.com/aic

Comment: @cleverpaul yes and it shows fine http://www.annsinkycreations.com/aic/images/pic01.jpg

Comment: @AnnAbdelzaher technically, you could just use:

background: #333333 url("http://annsinkycreations.com/aic/images/pic01.jpg") !important; no-repeat;

However, not the greatest solution.

Comment: @AnnAbdelzaher is this happening in specific page or in the index (home) page? because  when I go to the site I can see the image in the background.

Comment: @AnnAbdelzaher try clearing your web cache. Also, open the web inspector (F12 for Chrome) and see if there are any 404 errors in the console.

Comment: it is happening on all pages the internal pages are supposed to have a scaled version of it

Comment: I can see the image background in site... is there any specific page where image not show?

Comment: @cleverpaul hmm for some reason it is saying it can't find the picture but it is there ...

Comment: @AnnAbdelzaher What I see when I go to your site [image](http://imgur.com/a/ewDjP) I think the problem is with your browser. It might be showing a cached version of the web site to make the site fast. Clear all the catch data restart the browser and try again.

Comment: OK guys I don't know what happened but it is suddenly there! I should have known to clear the dang cache.. first line of defense but the darn thing was there last week so I didn't think anything of it.

Comment: I guess I was having a blonde moment or something.. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

For those of you not wanting to read through the comments. I was unable to see the picture, other helping me were. the simple solution was to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute path location

try first to view it in the browser "http://www.site.ext/images/pic01.jpg" if it exists then

```
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  background-image: url('http://www.site.ext/images/pic01.jpg');
```

or

```
  background: url('http://www.site.ext/images/pic01.jpg') #f1f1f1;
```